# Validate referential integrity of object arrays with Joi

Tags: joi, frisby.js

I'm trying to validate that the data I am returned it sensible. Validating data types is done. Now I want to validate that I've received all of the data needed to perform a task.

Here's a representative example:

```
{
  "things": [
    {
      "id": "00fb60c7-520e-4228-96c7-13a1f7a82749",
      "name": "Thing 1",
      "url": "https://lolagons.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "709b85a3-98be-4c02-85a5-e3f007ce4bbf",
      "name": "Thing 2",
      "url": "https://lolfacts.com"
    }
  ],
  "layouts": {
    "sections": [
       {
          "id": "34f10988-bb3d-4c38-86ce-ed819cb6daee",
          "name": "Section 1",
          "content:" [
             {
               "type": 2,
               "id": "00fb60c7-520e-4228-96c7-13a1f7a82749" //Ref to Thing 1
             }
          ]
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

So every Section references 0+ Things, and I want to validate that every `id` value returned in the Content of Sections also exists as an `id` in Things.

The docs for [Object.assert(..)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.6.0/API.md#objectassertref-schema-message) implies that I need a concrete reference. Even if I do the validation within the Object.keys or Array.items, I can't resolve the reference at the other end.

Not that it matters, but my context is that I'm validating HTTP responses within [IcedFrisby](https://github.com/MarkHerhold/IcedFrisby), a Frisby.js fork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't really solveable in the way I asked (i.e. with Joi).

I solved this for my context by writing a plugin for icedfrisby (published on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icedfrisby-jsonrefchecks)) which uses jsonpath to fetch each `id` in Content and each `id` in Things. The plugin will then assert that all of the first set exist within the second.